# Upgrade from EF Core 1.1 to 2.0 preview

Tags: entity-framework-core

After upgrading EF1.1 to EF2.0 now I'm not able to do migrations.

> Error: Startup project 'QilinSystem.Store.Data.csproj' targets
>   framework '.NETStandard'. This framework is not intended for execution
>   and may fail to resolve runtime dependencies. If so, specify a
>   different project using the --s tartup-project option and try again.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`EF Core 2.0 Preview 1` requires Visual Studio 15.3 Preview, so you have to install it.

[Announcing EF Core 2.0 Preview 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/12/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-1/):

> Accessing .NET Core tooling in Visual Studio requires Visual Studio
>   2017 15.3 Preview, Visual Studio for Mac or Visual Studio Code. More
>   information about this and download links can be found in the .NET
>   Core 2.0 Preview 1 announcement.

[Visual Studio Preview FAQ](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/):

> Preview installs next to your stable Visual Studio IDE, allowing you
>   to use either independently.